# Eevee fire not rendering correctly

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, fire

Been struggling with this for a couple of days now and can't seem to find any answers online. Lots of people claiming to have solved the problem but still getting many problems trying to render in eevee.
My process is as follows:

Open new file,
create circle with ngon,
apply quick smoke to circle,
change domain to adaptive,
change circles flow type to fire,
Enable volumetric lighting (enabled by default)

That is literally it. It renders perfectly in solid view but in eevee it only shows the smoke. Tried this on two machines with the same result. I did manage to get it to work once by playing with settings but then it seemed to trip up somehow and stopped rendering. After searching online this seems to be a very frequent problem for a lot of users so seems like something has to be up with it.

I have tried it on version 2.82 and version 2.83.4. My home build is as follows:

windows 10 pro
32gb ram
Nvidea 2070 rtx
intel core i7-7700k cpu

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I went back to version 2.8 and everything worked fine. It seems like a much more stable version for doing this sort of simulation.